# How long would it take to transfer a 10gb folder over bluetooth?

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook, bluetooth

How long would it take to transfer 10GB folder from 1 Macbook to another using Bluetooth?

Comment: You do realize that you asked a [related question](http://superuser.com/questions/227825/transfering-a-15gb-folder-from-1-macbook-to-another) yesterday, and none of the answers recommended using Bluetooth -- for a reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, practical data transfer rate is 2.1 Mbit/s or  0.2625 MB/s. Therefore it would take approx. 10.5 hours.

Comment: Macbooks all have Bluetooth 2.0+EDR or 2.1+EDR. The sections about these are the source of your numbers.