# How to copy files between two macs connected with Airport Extreme?

Tags: macos, lan, file-transfer, airport-extreme

I have two Macs connected to an Airport Extreme wireless network. I would like to transfer files over this network. Would appreciate step by step instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Open *System Preferences » Sharing*

Enable *File Sharing* and make sure in *Options...* that the topmost option (AFP) is checked.

[image]

Now you can access that machine's files from the other one by clicking its icon in the Finder sidebar.

---

Transferring large files over wireless network takes ages. [Have a look at this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/227825/transfering-a-15gb-folder-from-1-macbook-to-another/227826#227826).